# Setting up a config.inc.php file

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin, privileges

So I am trying access the privileges tab in phpmyadmin which is currently not showing. I have tried everything from deleting cookies to adding new users through the control panel. Nothing has worked so far but I have read that by altering the config.inc.php you can make the tab show. I cannot locate mine so I am looking to make another. Can someone guide me through this process?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: Does your MySQL user have access to adjust privileges in the MySQL database in the first place?

Comment: When the user was created in the control panel it said that I was granted all DBO privileges, so the user should have access. FYI, I can create a database on the control panel but not in phpmyadmin when logged in with the user.

Comment: This means you have no idea what access rights you have. You should check it (see `show grants`).

Comment: Okidoke, so I have these options, some are clicked and some aren't:      Partial texts
Full texts
Show binary contents
Show BLOB contents
Show binary contents as HEXHide browser transformation Geometry
 Well Known Text
 Well Known Binary

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with these options. It doesn't look like I have full privileges.